# Remove clients who don't have 2 rows by their name in SQL

Tags: sql, databricks

What I'm trying to do is to filter by the clients that registered twice in the DB. This as I need to know who of them came at least twice, that is why I´m working with a table that registers every time they registered in the system as it follows:

| order # | client | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Andrew | XX |
| Two | Andrew | XX+1 |
| Three | Andrew | XX+2 |
| One | David | YY |
| One | Marc | ZZ |
| Two | Marc | ZZ+1 |

In this case I want to delete David´s record, as I only want people who has order numbers distinct than "one".

I tried this SQL:

```
select * 
from table 
where order_number > 1
```

however what this does is remove all the rows of the first orders, including the ones that came back.

Does somebody know an easy way for me to compare row names and filter by that or just how could I delete those rows in which there are clients with only one entry?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: Sometimes you say DELETE, sometimes SELECT... Do you want to SELECT users having at least 2 rows, or do you want to DELETE users from the table having only 1 row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this :

```
select * from yourtable 
where not exists (select 1 from yourtable where order_number >1)
```

or:

```
select client 
from tablename
group by client
having count(*) > 1
```